# Pause Electron with a hotkey or similar

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, electron

In our Electron app I'd like to use the dev tools to inspect an element that only exists if a parent element experiences a mouseover action.

Whenever I go to interact with the dev tools my mouse has to move and the element disappears.

I know that the Chrome dev tools usually pause script execution with f8. This does not seem to work in Electron. I have also tried forcing the parent elements into :hover and :focus in the dev tools, but this does nothing.

Any ideas please on how to pause execution or force a parent into :hover?

Answer (score 0):

After some more fooling around I found that if I inspect a parent element, right click on that element in the dev tools, and then click on `Break on...`, and click on `subtree modification`. I can then get the debugger going without having to insert any `debugger;` statements into the code.